# Passing data between react native components not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been following the instructions in [this document](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pass-data-between-components-in-react/), and have tried some answers from other questions on this website, but none of them are printing the props on the page. Not sure if I'm calling it wrong, or not passing the data properly. Have posted my parent, and 3 separate attempts at getting the child to work. Nothing shows on the page. I have imported child component into parent page, and { component } in child page.

parent:

```
const ToyDetails = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  const parentToChild = () => {
    setData(name)
  }

  return (
    <View>
        <CardCard parentToChild={data}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>parentToChild()}
          <Text>{buttonText}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

child (CartCard.js) attempt 1: prints data on parent page

```
export default class CartCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{data}</Text>
        </View>
      )
   }
}
```

child attempt 2: prints nothing on either page

```
export default class CartCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.parentToChild}</Text>
        </View>
      )
   }
}
```

child attempt 3: prints data on parent page

```
const CartCard = ({parentToChild}) => {
   
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{parentToChild}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default CartCard
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors or just that data is not passed to a child?

Comment: Just checked the console. I get no error messages, but I do get this warning: Require cycle: Components\CartCard.js -> Screens\ToyDetails.js -> Components\CartCard.js. Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to pass data to children component as props, based on your code
https://snack.expo.dev/peRi9sELk
Its hard to say whats going wrong for you, but in order to see a change being reflected in your components, you have to cause a re-render of the component tree. The easiest way to do that is by changing state.

Comment: Just tried it out. It only works if all of that stays on the same page/file, I'm trying to have them on different pages/files.